# What could cause this LCD ghosting issue happening frequently on multiple devices?

Tags: lcd

We’re getting an unusually high number of returned devices with a peculiar screen issue appearing.

It’s always dark on the right hand side of the white text and sometimes makes the left hand side lighter. Some of them are flickering but most are just a bad ghosting artefact.

Lowering the brightness diminishes the effect, but doesn’t remove it completely.

These devices are being left on, on this screen, for months at a time. On a previous model of devices this wasn’t an issue, besides screen burn, but these newer devices that we’ve been using the last couple of years are presenting a high occurrence of this issue.

Here’s a couple of examples:

[image: LCD ghosting issue] [image: LCD ghosting issue]

[image: LCD ghosting issue]

I’ve opened a few up and can’t see any signs of water damage. I’ve also tried swapping the screen and for at least one have ascertained that the problem is within the LCD screen, by swapping it with a good one which resolved the issue.

Turning it off for a few days usually helps, often fixing it if it’s switched off for a good while. At least temporarily.

Sometimes it happens after a few months whereas other devices after more than a year. And other devices have no issue being on for so long.

Could it be caused by the image being near static, or on high brightness? Or is it more likely a hardware fault?

The manufacturer keeps defaulting back to it being “screen burn” which doesn’t look like any kind of screen burn I’ve ever seen!

Any clues of what could cause this type of problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: A guess: You have got bad hardware. Bad connections, fake parts or both of them. If you have ordered your stuff from far East you have a problem. Claiming or even proving there's hardware faults leads to nothing. You will get polite answers like "we deliver the best quality devices made with highest manufacturing standards. Have a good new year!"  A local partner may be able to resolve the problem so that nobody must lose his face in front of you. Or not. Start a process to find an alternative source.

Comment: Someone somewhere designed this product. Find them and speak to them.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site and well done for writing a good-quality question. What quantities do you buy, p.c.m. or p.a.? If the manufacturer's being evasive, as you describe, then you've got little actual leverage over them unless you're ordering high quantities they will miss. Are you tied to this supplier, how many units do you have in the field? Are you using this unit clearly within its manf specifications? Are you relying on a characteristic the manf spec doesn't cover? Please edit this info into your question text (not under 'EDIT' at the end), not in comments. Again, welcome.

Comment: LCD devices do not like DC and just a little will cause problems. I would suggest taking a very close look at the driver outputs and look for possibly a small DC offset.

Comment: Thanks @Gil -do you know if that could be related to the power adapters themselves? We've had a few bad ones of those too, from a different company. Or would it be more likely contained to the inputs/outputs within the actual device?

Comment: It is possible. Run several as they are now and also several on PURE DC and see what happens. Have you tried a different batch of drivers from a different manufacturer and supplier?

Comment: I'll do some research on how to do that. I've managed to ascertain that there's a slight bow/twist occurring in the screens for a few different reasons.. and after getting my hands on this particular device the issue improved when I opened it up and released some of the torque. Furthermore, I was able to worsen or improve the issue very slightly by deliberately flexing the screen... my assumption from that, without much knowledge, would be that the devices are bending and the screen is getting damaged by that. Maybe fractures in the LCD circuitry? Would that make sense to you as an engineer?